# Launch watchkit app from long custom notification content area

Tags: watchkit, apple-watch

I'm trying to implement a feature such that users can click on the notification content area (not app icon nor action buttons) to bring the main watchkit app open. The current official way to launch the main watchkit app is to tap the app icon or action buttons in a notification scene. But I feel like the app icon is actually quite small (and hard) to tap and sometimes users are not even aware of this feature.

What I'm trying to do now is to put my notification content into a table row in the notification controller and make this row clickable. This will give user a pretty big area to tap with. Then in the click event handler I'm trying to open the main watchkit app. But I haven't figure out a way to do that (none of the general navigation methods such as presentControllerWithName works from notification controller).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you try tapping a notification? In my case it shows up the full app.

Comment: @SeyyedParsaNeshaei Did you mean tap on notification app icon? Yes, that will open the full app. But I want to extend the tap area to the notification content not just the app icon

Comment: No, I mean the body of the notification. The text and details, not buttons or sash, according to Apple Watch Programming Guide available at developer.apple.com.